# Oats a negative aspect for skinny people?

Tags: weight-gain, muscle-mass, muscle-gain

I am underweight and skinny, I am 5.8 and only 120lbs.

I eat a blended shake of milk, oats and banana. I hear that oats is not good to advantage for people looking on to put some mass.

Is this true? What things could I eat to gain some mass?

Comment: Please see the questions on gaining weight on the site. There's plenty of great info on the topic here.

Comment: I edited the question, feel free to revert the changes or edit it again.

Comment: Voted to close as off topic, in the current form it is only questioning one unsourced nutrition myth, however, nutrition unrelated to exercise is off topic here on the site, check the [faq].

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the referenced post a mention on OATS. So how can this post be a duplicate.

Comment: The other question contains information about what you could eat to gain mass. Please read over the answers there more thoroughly and search this site.

Answer (score 1):

Oats are Healthy, trying to find a replacement for them that is "healthier" is difficult near impossible.

The problem with oats and putting on weight is that they have a low calorie density and also are low GI. So you feel fuller for longer while only eating a little.

As someone who is going to want to be eating lots the low GI can make it a little difficult as trying to eat another big meal when already full is a struggle.

Personally I never gave up oats, my breakfast is normally 100g of oats with some toast (Grass-fed, unsalted butter) and a protein shake. You feel like you are going to explode and it takes a while to get used to it.

Then I go to the gym straight away and try to build up my appetite. Then have a post workout meal.

Again it takes time to adjust to eating lots but you have to be patient.

Try to make up the calories elsewhere because oats for breakfast is kinda amazing in every other aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Oats is a super food and is good for most people, whether skinny or fat! It is a constant in my diet for years, especially in breakfast. You can include a variety of other cereals in your diet to make it more balanced. You can also increase the protein content in your diet to put on some mass, along with high quality cooking oil like olive or rice bran.

Oats lowers the cholesterol and has high iron content, while it is true that it is low calorie, you can add raisins, nuts, sugar and full fat milk to increase the calorific value. Cholesterol may not be a problem for you right now, but it is always good to keep it in control as we age..